# How exactly node == null checks if the stack is full?

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, stack-overflow

If the new node we created is null (nothing), how is it not referring to the stack as empty but instead checks if the stack is full?

```
 //push() function

public void push(int x) {
    
    //create a new node and allocate memory
    Node node = new Node();

    //check if the stack is full i.e check for stack overflow
    if(node == null) {
        System.out.println("\n Stack is full. Stack Overflow!");
        return;
    }
    node.data = x;
    node.next = head;
    head = node;
}

//check for an empty stack
public boolean isEmpty() { 
    return head == null;
}
```

Comment: The `if(node == null)` check is useless and will never be true. When the memory is full, then there will be an error message.

Comment: The one who wrote this code likely (mistakenly) thought that if the stack is full, `new Node()` would not be executed (?) and so `node` will stay null, but that's not true. If the stack is full, a `StackOverflowError` will be thrown.

Comment: Also, new variables are created in the heap, not stack memory. The error you'll get if the memory is full is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

Comment: So, you mean the statement actually checks if the memory is full but not the stack overflow?

Comment: Where is this code from?

Comment: @KalashBabuAcharya No. If the new Node can't be created, you will get an Exception rather than returning null. So the check for null doesn't do anything and could hide the real problem.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-a-stack-using-singly-linked-list/

The code is referred from geeksforgeeks site.

Comment: There is a code in java too. Please have a second look.

Comment: It too is garbage, for the reasons stated above. Obviously transliterated from the C++ without aforethought. But the change from `"heap overflow"` to `"stack overflow"` remains yours.

Comment: Unfortunately, GeeksForGeeks don't provide a way to downvote / unlike low quality articles.  So they have a quality control issue.  Reader beware!

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, the code you’re referencing isn’t very good. :-)

As noted in the comments, the Java code you’ve posted here can never have that `if` check pass, since if there’s no memory when the allocation is made the code will generate an `OutOfMemoryError` rather than leaving the reference null. The C++ code that’s linked also can’t have the `if` statement trigger, since in C++ if `new` runs out of memory it will throw a `std::bad_alloc` exception.